# What is the difference between a communicating class and a closed communicating class?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

What is the difference between a communicating class and a closed communicating class?

I checked the definition on Wikipedia
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Properties
but I couldn't see any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the only nonzero transitions on the state space $\{a,b,c\}$ are $a\to b$, $b\to a$, $b\to c$, and $c\to c$. Then $\{a,b\}$ and $\{c\}$ are communicating classes, $\{a,b\}$ is not a closed communicating class, and $\{c\}$ is a closed communicating class.

Comment: in the example you explained if I take $a\rightarrow b, b \rightarrow c, c\rightarrow a, a \rightarrow a  $ then $\{a\}$ is a closed communicating class and $\{a,b,c\}$ is also a closed communicating class, can we say that $\{b,c\}$ is also a closed communicating class? Thanks!

Comment: Can we say that irreducible Markov chains are closed because an irreducible Markov chain has only one class?